# Lightning container : index.html not in the right folder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, folder

I try to use the lightning container to display an element in a salesforce component.
So, I have this code :

```
<aura:component access="global">
    <lightning:container aura:id="timeline"
        src="{!$Resource.myProject+ '/index.html'}"/>
</aura:component>
```

But it doesn't work, the browser try to load the index.html file in the wrong address :

> myaddress.container.lightning.com/lcc/1501081198000/myProject/index.html?sfdcIFrameOrigin=myaddress.lightning.force.com

whereas the file is at this address :

> myaddress.lightning.force.com/resource/1501081198000/myProject/index.html

My index.html file is in the static resource folder.

So, do you know how I can do to take the file on the right folder or how I can choose the folder ?

Comment: Having the same issue. My LCC component has the right resource syntax according to the doc, but when rendering in the app, it shows a /lcc/path/to/resource.html in the iframe that doesn't resolve. Manually updating the iframe src in the rendered HTML to /resource/path/to/resource.html makes it render properly.

Comment: Guys, Im following https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_examples.htm Realty App from Salesforce Official Documentation, but following the same steps as they are describing, I have Realty App blocked on Browser (Refused to display ... in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'. ) so official example doesn't work at all (working with API version 41).

Comment: Seeing the same X-Frame Options issue as well here.

Comment: Did someone fine any workaround for this?

Answer (score 5):

Just one additinal information to the previous one:

If I try to load directly the html from the resolve URL without the lcc in the url like that:

```
<lightning:container aura:id="ReactApp"
                       src="https://pve-poc-dev-ed--c.container.lightning.com/lcc/1508416411000/schedulingComponentVisjs/index.html"
                       onmessage="{!c.handleMessage}"
                       onerror="{!c.handleError}"/>
```

I got this funny message from SF:

```
The src attribute must not begin with '/lcc/'. We received: /lcc/1508416411000/schedulingComponentVisjs/index.html
```

Answer (score 4):

I have exactly the same problem, I'm not even able to make the [Realty](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_example_realty.htm) example to work. I can access to my index.html from `https://pve-poc-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1508416411000/schedulingComponentVisjs/index.html` but as lightning:container resolve the URL to the index.html inside the static resources to `https://pve-poc-dev-ed--c.container.lightning.com/lcc/1508416411000/schedulingComponentVisjs/index.html`, it doesn't work.

Here the piece of code I'm using to load the container

```
  <lightning:container aura:id="ReactApp"
                       src="{!$Resource.schedulingComponentVisjs + '/index.html'}"
                       onmessage="{!c.handleMessage}"
                       onerror="{!c.handleError}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue at first, but then realized that the zip needed to be created at the same level as the index.html file, not the containing folder. For example:

Don't zip this whole folder

```
/ReactApp
  select all assets in here and make zip from that
  index.html
  manifest.json
  ... etc
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: This did help me and it works.